# Prevent other objects from accessing C array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I have a C array that contains the data for undoing the state of my drawing application. (It is an array of CGImageRefs) However, since I can't declare a C array as a property, all my instances are accessing the same array for undos. What's the easiest way to make it so that **only one object** can access a given C Array, preferably one it creates?

Comment: Use an `NSArray` property, and cast the `CGImageRef`s to `id` to add them.

Comment: You don't make sense.  If the array is addressed from a (non-public) ivar only methods of that object's class can address it.

Comment: @HotLicks Sounds like the array is currently a global & OP isn't sure how to have a C array as property/ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't declare a C array as a property

Sure you can:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGImageRef *imageArray;
```

A few other pointers:

- [You can store CGImageRefs in NSArrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) (using a `__bridge` cast to convert to `id` type), which is usually much easier.
- You should probably be using [NSUndoManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to implement undo management.

Comment: Oh thanks! I am using NSUndoManager, but the UndoManager uses the array to revert the changes- it registers an undo with an imageRef from the array, passing it to another method.

Comment: Why not just pass the CGImageRef directly to the undo manager? You generally don't need to track any state for undo management if you're using NSUndoManager.

Comment: Well, yes, I was using,  [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]performUndoOrRedoWithValueForImage:imageArray[undoCount]; Was I missing something?

Comment: Just register the reverse of your current action. So if you're calling `[self setImage:newImage]`, then call `[[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setImage:[self image]]` first.

Comment: Well the issue is that the setting of the variable is in another object owned by my NSDocument subclass. Since I can't do anything with the undo manager from there, I have my document retain copies of the canvas image in an array. Maybe I just need to restructure.